# Getting session cookie with jQuery security

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, nowjs-sockets

Are there any security issues with getting a cookie with jquery and sending it via nowjs function as opposed to getting it via the request on the server?

```
var session = $.cookie('session_cookie');

now.distributeMessage(session);
```

vs

```
req.headers.cookie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the reason to send cookies from the browser side, since they are transmitted either way each time you make a request to the server. No need to duplicate this feature, just use:

```
req.headers.cookie
```

Answer (score 0):

In an iframe in IE (perhaps an edge case) cookies are not always sent (unless you transmit a security policy --which gets complicated--).  It is just easier to use Javascript cookies and pass them by socket.emits (or by the convenient now.calls).